# Why is VSCode with Firefox debugger giving me an incorrect value?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, firefox-developer-tools

I have been trying to solve an issue with a (javascript) project and seem to have been put on entirely the wrong track by what appears to be a bug in the debugger - or am I missing something?
[image: screenshot of vscode]

When I finally got round to looking at the 'watch' window, it showed me a different value from that shown by hovering on the same variable in the editor window (as shown in the snip, taken while hovering over `].type`).

`trackGrid[toRow][toCol].type` is currently "EE" and not "BL" as shown. "BL" is the value it is *going to be given*. It's because I have the same variable name for the new value and the member of the object array that I am replacing. I now know to use use a different local variable name, or to ignore the 'popup' value, but this has thrown me off track for hours.

### **[edit]**

Thanks to "user"'s comment I have now discovered tha the issue is only with Firefox in VSCode. The code below shows the issue when run with the firefox debugger, but not with Chrome. If the Firefox debugger is used in the browser itself (using `inspect`) it shows the value as `undefined` - which isn't correct either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Firefox debugger bug?</h2>
<p>Add breakpoint to line 25 and hover on 'type' of <i>trackGrid[row][col].type</i></p>

<button onclick="testFunc(1,1)">Run demo</button>

<script>
  const trackGrid= [];

  function init() {
    trackGrid[0] = [];
    trackGrid[1] = [];
    trackGrid[0][0] = { "type" : "AA",  "id": 0 };
    trackGrid[0][1] = { "type" : "AB",  "id": 1 };
    trackGrid[1][0] = { "type" : "BA",  "id": 10 };
    trackGrid[1][1] = { "type" : "BB",  "id": 11 };
  }

  function testFunc(row,col) {
    init();
    var type = "XX";
    trackGrid[row][col].type = type;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Just the default Firefox debug - `launch.json` below.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Open  with firefox",
            "file": "c:\\Users\\quilk\\source\\repos\\vscodebug\\test.html"
            
          },

        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Open  with chrome",
            "file": "c:\\Users\\quilk\\source\\repos\\vscodebug\\test.html"
        },
        {
            "type": "msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Open with Edge",
            "file": "c:\\Users\\quilk\\source\\repos\\vscodebug\\test.html"
          }

    ]
}
```